# URL parameter encoding/receiving problem

Tags: java, encoding

I use the below code to send data to a servlet:
When encoding = "UTF-8" or "GBK", the data is received correctly.
But when encoding = "UTF-16", The receiver receives null. WHY??

The Sender:

```
    URL url = new URL(notifyURL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=" + encoding);        
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write("notify_id=" + URLEncoder.encode("123", encoding) + "&notify_type=" + URLEncoder.encode("any", encoding));
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    connection.connect();
```

The receiver servlet:

```
            log.info(request.getParameter("notify_type"));    //print null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Javadocs for [URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you should only use UTF-8 because other encodings may cause problems. They link directly to the W3C spec from the Javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues,

1. UTF-16 is not supported by lots of web servers. Some URLDecoder can only handle single byte encoding (ASCII, Latin-1) and UTF-8.
2. You are using mixed encoding if your default encoding is not UTF-16. UTF-8 and GBK are both ASCII compatible (ASCII is encoded as itself) so you can mix with ASCII but you can't do that with UTF-16.